# asp.net website publishing / deploying

Tags: asp.net, web-deployment

How do I publish/deploy an asp.net website to a live server (like a goDaddy server)?
I moved all the files to the remote server without dataaccess layer and business layer. Move dlls to bin folder on live server. But when I try to browse website it gives errors like:

> Could not load file or assembly 'BusLayer' or one of its dependencies. This assembly is built by a runtime newer than the currently loaded runtime and cannot be loaded.
>
> Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.
> Exception Details: System.BadImageFormatException: Could not load file or assembly 'BusLayer' or one of its dependencies. This assembly is built by a runtime newer than the currently loaded runtime and cannot be loaded.

Please help me handle these errors. I am not very good at English; maybe there are a lot of mistakes in my question. Thanks in advance for help.

Comment: kindly guide me in detailed steps.

Comment: Are you using external files like DLL?

Comment: What version are you running locally, and what's on your server? It almost looks like your error message is flagging a framework mismatch.

Comment: PiLHA i dnt use external files like DLL.

Comment: Tim my server version is ASP.Net 2.0/3.0/3.5

Answer (score 1):

I assume Bus layer means business layer. I believe that your presentation layer has some dependencies on the business layer. Now since you didn't push the business layer to production (remote server), its looking for a file and not finding it and hence the error.

the fix i guess will be to move all your files to remote server and try browsing files that doesn't have database dependencies (Again, assuming you don't have a database at production)

Comment: i have database which is created on server. moved all the files to server but still issue is appear

Answer (score 0):

"This assembly is built by a runtime newer than the currently loaded runtime and cannot be loaded." usually means that you have a .NET version issue. Is the BusLayer assembly on the server compiled under a newer version that the web site?

Also, does the app run locally? If so, publish all the contents of your local BIN.

I hope you made a backup of your site prior to deployment.